# Swift error: cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type '() -> () -> $T1'

Tags: swift

I'm learning Apple's new programming language Swift. I was trying to add a new method `printAll` to `Array` instances, using Swift extensions, which when called will print all elements in the array

```
extention Array { 
    func printAll() {
        for (i, value) in enumerate(self) {
            println("\(i+1). \(value)")
        }
    }
}

// let someAppleProducts = ["iPhone", "iPad", "iWatch", "iMac"]

// someAppleProducts.printAll()
```

But I'm getting following error while running above script using a online compiler [runswiftlang.com](http://www.runswiftlang.com/):

```
error: cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type '() -> () -> $T1'
extention Array {
          ^~~~~~~~
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error?

---

However, adding `times` method to `Int` instances works fine

```
extension Int {
    func times(task: () -> ()) {
        for _ in 0..<self {
            task()
        }
    }
}

3.times({
    println("Hello!")
})
```

Prints:

```
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
```

Comment: Simple typo: `extention` --> `extension`.

Comment: I'd argue against closing the question as a typo question - yes, it was caused by a simple typo, but the error message really isn't clear and the OP isn't the only one that's going to have this issue. I could see this question helping users in the future.

Comment: I agree with @Undo. Error message is misleading. Please don't downvote this question as it will help users in the future

Comment: @Undo: I disagree. It is a simple typo. The compiler points at the wrong line.  Comparing the faulty line with the working example shows the difference immediately. And what are the chances that another user accidentally types `extention`, gets the *same error message* and then finds this Q&A ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misspelled `extension`:

```
extention Array {
```

should be

```
extension Array {
```

The error message for this is misleading, I would expect it to be something like `unrecognized token 'extention'` or something helpful!